# How to format a string expression in the report viewer?

Tags: string, format, report, reportviewer, viewer

I need to add a hyphen in the middle of a string.

**input**

```
AAA0000
```

**desired output**

```
AAA-0000
```

I think it's something like:

> =Format(First(Fields!test.Value, "myDataSet"), "?????")

but I am unsure.

Can anyone suggest how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

If your input is always a string with 3 alphanumeric characters followed by 4 numeric characters you can use:

```
=Left(First(Fields!test.Value), 3) & "-" & Right(First(Fields!test.Value), 4)
```